# Spark dataframe filter with boolean list comprehension

Tags: apache-spark, filter, pipe, list-comprehension, where-clause

I want to filter a spark dataframe `sdf` based on several columns being not null.

Imagine I have:

```
labels = ["A", "B, C"]
```

This would work:

```
sdf.where(sf.col(labels[0]).isNotNull() | sf.col(labels[1]).isNotNull() | sf.col(labels[2]).isNotNull())
```

But I would like to do something similar to a list comprehension if the list was much longer:

```
sdf.where(any([sf.col(l).isNotNull() for l in labels]))
```

(this does not work, {ValueError}Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` from `functools` to iterate over your list of columns and apply your logic.

In your case, it looks like you want to grab all the rows where any column has a non-null value (so full null value rows should get filtered away).

```
from functools import reduce
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

labels = ["A", "B", "C"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (None, 1,    "ABC"),
        (1,    None, "BCD"),
        (None, None, None),
        (2,    2,    None),
        (1,    3,    "DEF"),
        (2,    1,    "EFG"),
        (None, None, None),
        (2,    2,    None),
        (None, 3,    "HIJ"),
        (None, None, None),
        (2,    2,    None),
        (3,    1,    "EFG"),
        (3,    2,    None),
        (None, None, None),
        (2,    2,    None),
        (3,    3,    "HIJ"),
    ],
    ["A", "B", "C"]
)

df.filter(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y,  (F.col(x).isNotNull() for x in labels))).show()
+----+----+----+
|   A|   B|   C|
+----+----+----+
|null|   1| ABC|
|   1|null| BCD|
|   2|   2|null|
|   1|   3| DEF|
|   2|   1| EFG|
|   2|   2|null|
|null|   3| HIJ|
|   2|   2|null|
|   3|   1| EFG|
|   3|   2|null|
|   2|   2|null|
|   3|   3| HIJ|
+----+----+----+
```

As you can see, the rows with all `null` values are correctly filtered away. This is done by OR-ing the `isNotNull()` conditions.